# React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'handleLogout'. Either include it or remove the dependency array react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, redux-toolkit

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import LoginModal from "./LoginModal";
import { NavLink, useLocation, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { userLogout } from "../Features/User/userSlice";
import decode from "jwt-decode";

const Header = ({ toggleModalShow, showModal }) => {

  const [burgerAnimation, setBurgerAnimation] = useState(false);
  const [user, setUser] = useState();
  const location = useLocation();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  // for showing login/sign up modal
  const showModalButton = () => {
    toggleModalShow();
  };

  const handleBurgerAnimation = () => {
    setBurgerAnimation(!burgerAnimation);
  };

  const handleLogout = async (id) => {
    await dispatch(userLogout({ id, navigate, dispatch }));
    setUser(null);
  };

  const burgerListItemAnimation = ...
  const burgerIconAnimation = ...

  const guestHeader = (
    <ul>
       ...
    </ul>
  );

  const userHeader = (
    <ul>
       ...
    </ul>
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    if (localStorage.getItem("user") && !user) {
      setUser(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user")));
    }

    const accessToken = user?.accessToken;

    if (accessToken) {
      const decodedAccessToken = decode(accessToken);

      if(decodedAccessToken.exp * 1000 < new Date().getTime()){
        handleLogout(user.user._id);
      }
      console.log(decodedAccessToken);
    }
  }, [location, user]);

  return (
    <header className="header">
        ...
    </header>
  );
};

export default Header;
```

Hi all.I just wanted to try to log out the user when the expiration date is over. If i put `'handleLogout'` to useEffect dependicies warning doesnt change. Why am i getting this warning ? What kind of warning may i get if i dont fix that ? And finally, if you have time to review the repo, would you give feedback ?

repo : https://github.com/UmutPalabiyik/mook

Comment: Highly, highly recommend [this blog post by Dan Abramov.](https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you keep `handleLogout` external to the `useEffect` hook it ***should*** be listed as a dependency as it is referenced within the hook's callback.

> If i put `handleLogout` to `useEffect` dependencies warning doesn't
> change.

I doubt the warning is the same. At this point I would expect to you to see the warning change to something like "the dependency `handleLogout` is redeclared each render cycle, either move it into the `useEffect` hook or memoize with `useCallback`..." something to that effect.

From here you've the 2 options.

1. Move `handleLogout` into the `useEffect` so it is no longer an external dependency.

   ```
   useEffect(() => {
     const handleLogout = async (id) => {
       await dispatch(userLogout({ id, navigate, dispatch }));
       setUser(null);
     };

     if (localStorage.getItem("user") && !user) {
       setUser(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user")));
     }

     const accessToken = user?.accessToken;

     if (accessToken) {
       const decodedAccessToken = decode(accessToken);

       if (decodedAccessToken.exp * 1000 < new Date().getTime()) {
         handleLogout(user.user._id);
       }
       console.log(decodedAccessToken);
     }
   }, [location, user, id, navigate, dispatch]);
   ```
2. Memoize `handleLogout` with `useCallback` so it's a stable reference ***and*** add it to the effect's dependencies.

   ```
   const handleLogout = useCallback(async (id) => {
     await dispatch(userLogout({ id, navigate, dispatch }));
     setUser(null);
   }, [id, navigate, dispatch]);
   ```

   ...

   ```
   useEffect(() => {
     if (localStorage.getItem("user") && !user) {
       setUser(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user")));
     }

     const accessToken = user?.accessToken;

     if (accessToken) {
       const decodedAccessToken = decode(accessToken);

       if (decodedAccessToken.exp * 1000 < new Date().getTime()) {
         handleLogout(user.user._id);
       }
       console.log(decodedAccessToken);
     }
   }, [location, user, handleLogout]);
   ```

Comment: Yes i am sorry if i put handleLogout to useEffect dependencies i get 'The 'handleLogout' function makes the dependencies of useEffect Hook (at line 112) change on every render. To fix reac this, wrap the definition of 'handleLogout' in its own useCallback() Hook ...'